# How to improve LLDB debugging startup time in Linux

Tags: linux, debugging, lldb

I have a mid size cross-platform application that I can start debugging in 2 to 3 seconds from click "Start Debugging" to hitting a breakpoint at the top of the `main()` method. This is when built with MSVC2019 toolset in Visual Studio.

The same application is also compiled under Ubuntu 20.04 and MacOS using clang-10 and debugged with LLDB. However, either in VSCode or Qt Creator it takes about 15 seconds from click "Start debugging" to hitting the same breakpoint. It looks like the majority of the time is spent loading symbols from the shared objects. On MacOS, despite being developed with a MacBook and not having a powerful desktop CPU, it loads in about 6 seconds, i.e. faster.

Compiler args being used:

```
clang -x c++ -std=c++17 -O0 -g -fPIC -fmessage-length=0 -fstrict-aliasing -stdlib=libc++ -isystem "/usr/lib/llvm-10/include/c++/v1/" -isystem "/usr/include" -MMD -MF $out.d -o $out -c $in
```

Linker args being used:

```
clang -O0 -fPIC -fmessage-length=0 -fstrict-aliasing -stdlib=libc++ -g -fvisibility=hidden -pedantic-errors -fobjc-arc -z noexecstack -z relro -z now -lc++ -lc++abi -lm -lrt -shared -Wl,-rpath,'$$ORIGIN',-z,origin -o $out @$out.rsp
```

My question is, is there a well known combination of clang compiler/linker flags or lldb settings that can be tweaked to improve debugger startup time when developing on Linux?

I've tried `settings set target.preload-symbols false` on lldb init commands, but it didn't help much.

Comment: FWIW, using CLion's bundled `lldb` build certainly improved the startup time over the version available in APT from Ubuntu 20.04. If you are in VSCode with CodeLLDB extension and download CLion, adding this in settings.json will allow you to use their debugger: `"lldb.library": "/opt/clion-2020.2.1/bin/lldb/linux/lib/liblldb.so",`

Comment: Did you ever find any other way to make this faster? I have a large program that literally takes 10mins to startup from loading symbols from `so`s (using vscode lldb)

Comment: @David, no, unfortunately CLion's bundled lldb is the fastest solution I've found so far. I have tweaked quite a few linker options, but they don't seem to make a difference.